# How do encourage my Ficus Lyrata to branch?

Tags: trees, plant-care, tree-care, ficus

I live in Sintra, Portugal and I have two Ficus Lyatra in a greenhouse with enough heat, water and fertilizer.

The problem is that they grow vertically and do not branch. They have already almost 3 meters tall and the leaves are beautiful, but I wanted them to branch out and become trees with a canopy. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a picture of a mature Ficus Lyrata.  They are massive trees up to 12 Meters tall.  They respond well to top pruning and will generate one or two shoots if the central leader is cut back.

Your choices are to wait and the plants will branch out on their own or cut the central leader and wait for it to grow new shoots at the tip.

Ficus are very hardy when in good light so you cannot make a mistake on where or when to cut.

[image: Ficus Lyrata]

Image By Forest & Kim Starr, CC BY 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=6115788